# <hr> tags on Bootstrap 5 has a diffrent color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have an issue using bootstrap-5 version, when I'm using `<hr>` and want to add background-color. The color is not accurate:

This is using bootstrap 4
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIY0P.png

This is using bootstrap 5
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drlow.png

I have tried using many colors and the results are the same, not accurate for bootstrap 5.

Anyone has the same issue?
Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: the example is using black color

Answer (score 2):

By checking the css applied by Bootstrap 5 to an hr tag you can find these few lines in the bootstrap-reboot.css file.

```
hr {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

The opacity set at 0.25 is what's causing the problem you mentioned.
If you want to have a fully saturated color just override the opacity with the following css code.

```
hr {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filippo V. is correct though perhaps a class would allow the default <hr tag to still be used. Something like this gives many options.

```
.hr-bw{
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #000);
  opacity: 1;
}

<hr class="hr-bw">
```